# A script that reads and outputs in a list in which rows it was used

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I'm using a .py file with "some text", then using my code to produce a dictionary of how many times a word is being used in the text.

```
{}    
for x in text:       

        x = x.lower()
```

**However**, I'm looking for a way to execute a list on which rows the element (i.e. x, words, isalpha, and more) is used, I do not want to include `for` or `if` etc.
To print out the script above, I use

```
filename = 'test.py'

        print(n, line, end='')
```

This is what I want in the final output:

```
1
2 words = {} 
          words[x] += 1

10 print(words)


x               
words         ]

lower        [3]
```

I'm assuming I could use *re Module*, however, I would appreciate tips

Comment: Do toy have any specific words you are looking for how many times each word appeared

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Why do you don't want to use 'if' and 'for'? Maybe try list comprehension?

Comment: Hello Filip and Alon, I'm sorry if my questioning isn't clear enough. I have a hard time wording myself. What I'm looking for is a way to print out on which row each "word" such as "x, words, isalpha..." is being used. I edited my post to clarify a bit more.

Comment: If your counting code works otherwise without problems, then just let it run and remove those unwanted words when it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

If I have clearly understand what you want to perform, you can use the following code:

```py
import re
from keyword import kwlist


i = 1
map = {}
with open("script.py", "r") as file:
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line: break

        # iterates over each real word on each line
        for x in re.split(r'[^\w]', line):
            # adds the world to the map only if it is not '', nor a number, nor a python keyword
            if x and not x.isdigit() and x not in kwlist:
                if not x in map: map[x] = [i]
                else: map[x].append(i)
        i += 1


# displays the map
for key in map:
    print(key, map[key], sep='\t\t')
```

This will produce :

```
words       [2, 6, 7, 9, 10]
x           [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9]
text        [3]
isalpha     [4]
lower       [5]
print       [10]
```

Comment: Hello, this worked fine! However, I do not understand a few parts of the code if you could guide or care to explain? "import builtins" isn't being used anywhere in the code.

Comment: You're right, it's a mistake on my part. I first tried to use builtins before using kwlist and i forget to remove it. Instead of `kwlist`, you can use `dir(builtins)` but you do not have the same words and I guess `kwlist` better respond to your case. I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I'm reading up about kwlist, however, there isnt much about it. Any reason to why you used it? Also if I had '#comments' in the .py file im importing, how would I make it not read throught it as well?_________________im trying to use line = re.sub(r'#.*$', '', line) however not to much sucess

Comment: I have chosen kwlist because it contains the default keywords of python and I've thought that what you wanted. If you do not want to read comments, you can modify the for loop with 
`for x in re.split(r'[^\w]', line.split('#')[0])`. This will keep only the first part of a line, everything after the `#` will not be taken into account. No need to use regex for this.